# Paginator/Sorting for dynamic data does not work

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-material

I have a data coming from an endpoint and put it into MatTableDataSource. I'm able to display the data but couldn't figure out a way to update the table when I want to use the pagination or the search, nothing is happening.

It's was easier when I Tried with a static data, but with dynamic data, I was only able to display all my data at once and note able to do more.

**What is the expected behavior?**

The table should refresh when switching pages via the paginator.

**What is the current behavior?**

The table does not refresh when switching pages via the paginator.

**What are the steps to reproduce?**

Unfortunately I can't provide a functional Plunker because the data I'm using comes from my backend app..

This is my current code (which is just displaying the data inside table neither the search or the pagination are working)

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Search ID</mat-label>
    <input  (keyup)="applySearch($event.target.value)" matInput placeholder="Filter" >
  </mat-form-field>
<table mat-table [dataSource]="certifications"   class="mat-elevation-z8">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ID </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cert"> {{ cert.num }} </td>
    </ng-container>
  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="NumO">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> NumO </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cert"> {{cert.NumO}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cert"> {{cert.Name}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Unit">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cert"> {{cert.Unit}} </td>
    </ng-container>


        <ng-container matColumnDef="State">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> State </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let cert"> {{cert.State}} </td>
          </ng-container>
          <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
          <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
        </table>
          <!-- YOU CAN CHANGE THE PAGE SIZE HERE -->
        <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[2, 4, 6]"   
      
      showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

produits.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Certification } from './produits';
import { ProduitService } from './produits.service'
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-produits',
  templateUrl: './produits.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./produits.component.scss'],
})
export class ProduitsComponent implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = [
    'num',
    'numO',
    'Name',
    'Unit',
    'State',
  ];
  certifications = new Array<Certification>()
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.certifications);

  applySearch(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }

  constructor(certService:ProduitService) {

    certService.getCertifications().subscribe(
      certifications => {
        this.certifications = certifications;
        console.log(this.certifications);
      }
    )

  }
  @ViewChild('paginator') paginator!: MatPaginator;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('heeeeeeeeeeeey')
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.certifications);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay first thing try to avoid calling api in your constructor it's not a good way,
second thing you pass the wrong data to your html [dataSource]="certifications" but
can i give you so simple and clear code

```js
/* Declaration */
displayedColumns: string[] = [
  'num',
  'numO',
  'Name',
  'Unit',
  'State',
];
/* this code will help you to refresh pagination  */
private paginator: MatPaginator;
private sort: MatSort;
@ViewChild(MatSort, {
  static: false
}) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
  this.sort = ms;
  this.setPaginationAndSort();
}
@ViewChild(MatPaginator, {
  static: false
}) set matPaginator(
  mp: MatPaginator
) {
  this.paginator = mp;
  this.setPaginationAndSort();
}
certifications: any = new MatTableDataSource([]);
constructor(public certService: ProduitService) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.getCertification()
}

getCertification() {
  this.certService.getCertifications().subscribe(
    certifications => {
      this.certifications = new MatTableDataSource(certifications);
      this.setPaginationAndSort()
      console.log(this.certifications);
    }
  )
}
setPaginationAndSort() {
  this.certifications.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.certifications.sort = this.sort;
}
  applySearch(filterValue: string) {
    this.certifications.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

  }
```

Comment: First of all thank you so much Jasmine, I tried to follow what you did unfortunately it didn't work, i got an error like  `Property 'certService' does not exist on type 'ProduitsComponent'.` after that I copied the body of getCertification(){...} and put it insde the constructor {}, and it did work like intended. I'm realy lost because now it's working but I don't know how to explain it.

Comment: constructor (public certService: ProductService) {} just add "public" before certService I forgot it and when you try to call the certService use "this.certService" and it will work,
the problem in your code that you are using a "certifications" array in your html but in the ts, you apply all the processing on the dataSource array that's why your table will not change

Comment: Working as intended, thank you so much Jasmine.